# Attach href to a class individually

Tags: javascript, class, dom

So I want to use Javascript to add three different href links to a class of 3 < li >
However I can't really get it to work properly.
I'm sorry for my short explanation and poor english, but I really don't know how to explain it any better.

I have googled away searching for a solution, but I can only find how to do it when you're not using a class.

HTML

```
<li class="navigation">HTML</li>
                <li class="navigation">DOM</li>
                <li class="navigation">Javascript</li>
            </ul>
```

JS

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");
  links[0].setAttribute('href', 'www.google.se');
```

I want to take the class named navigation and add an href link to the < li >.

Comment: Do you want to make the LI 'clickable' or do you want to wrap an <a> element around the text content?

Comment: I see no link. An li does not have an href.... You need to add a link inside of the li.

Comment: I want whatever shows up on the page to be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

The `li` element doesn't have an `href` attribute. It's a list item, not an anchor.

You can use `document.createElement` to create an `a` element, then move the text node inside the list item into it, then append the `a` element to the `li` element, then add an `href` attribute to it.

```js
const listitems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

Object.values(listitems).forEach(item => {
  const text = item.firstChild;
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.setAttribute("href", "http://google.com");
  item.appendChild(link);
  link.appendChild(text);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="navigation">HTML</li>
  <li class="navigation">DOM</li>
  <li class="navigation">Javascript</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: True, however this does not really solve the problem.
I want to be able to add different links to all of them.

Comment: @ChristoferCarlsson — So modify `link.setAttribute("href", "http://google.com");` based on whatever unstated condition you have for determining where each should link to.

Answer (score 0):

the li text, dont have click effect, so you add the link tag `<a></a>`

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");

links[0].setAttribute('href', 'www.google.se'); //edit the url
links[1].setAttribute('href', 'www.google.se');
links[2].setAttribute('href', 'www.google.se');
```

```html
<ul>  
  <li ><a class="navigation">HTML</a></li>
  <li ><a class="navigation">DOM</a></li>
  <li ><a class="navigation">Javascript<a/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var link1 = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation1");
var link2 = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation2");
var link3 = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation3");

link1[0].setAttribute('href', 'www.google.com');
link2[0].setAttribute('href', 'www.yahoo.com');
link3[0].setAttribute('href', 'www.test.com');
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="navigation1">HTML</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="navigation2">DOM</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="navigation3">Javascript</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```